# Filtering data in real time in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two problems strictly. The first is the problem with the field type in forms.py. Because I'm trying to use a foreign key as a value in the check box and I have the error that the "int () must be a string, a byte-like object or a number, not" ModelChoiceField "and I don't know what to do with it. The second main problem is data filtering in the interface in real time. What I mean? I have a user model like:

```py
# user/models.py:
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    country= models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(choices=YEARS, default=1)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
```

And in forms I want to see only those cities that are in the selected country. For example, we have record like:

```
London, United Kingdom;
York, United Kingdom; 
Berlin, Germany;
```

and if the user chooses Germany, he should only see Berlin in the area with the cities.
I hope you know what I want to achieve and someone will be able to help me.

```py
# forms.py:

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    country =forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all())
    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.filter(country=country))

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['website','country', 'city', 'year', 'image']


# city/models.py

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=7)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

EDIT:
I think you need this piece of code:

```py
@login_required
def profile(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Twoje dane zostały uaktualnione!')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy, don't worry. But you should use basic Ajax request for this so you'll learn something new, be happy!

Firstly, when If user doesn't select any country yet, we should hide all cities on form, or when user select undefined country (maybe you don't have city information in your country table) we should handle all errors. So add this lines to your form model:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['city'].queryset = City.objects.none()

        if 'country' in self.data:
            try:
                country_id = int(self.data.get('country'))
                self.fields['city'].queryset = City.objects.filter(country_id=country_id).order_by('name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty City queryset
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['city'].queryset = self.instance.country.city_set.order_by('name')
```

And add new function for get filtered cities when user select a country to your view before main view.
It looks like that:

```
def load_cities(request):
    country_id = request.GET.get('country')
    cities = City.objects.filter(country_id=country_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'city_dropdown_list_options.html', {'cities': cities})
```

This little function will request to 'country' field in your form and send filteder cities.
Let's create new html file in your directory like 'city_dropdown_list_options.html':

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for city in cities %}
<option value="{{ city.pk }}">{{ city.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Add new url to your urls.py:

```
path('ajax/load-cities/', views.load_cities, name='ajax_load_cities')
```

Now it’s time to create an AJAX request in your form. In the example below I’m using jQuery, but you can use any JavaScript framework (or just plain JavaScript) to create the asynchronous request:

```
{% block content %}

  <h2>Your Form</h2>

  <form method="post" id="ProfileUpdateForm" data-cities-url="{% url 'ajax_load_cities' %}" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <a href="{% url 'whatyouwant' %}">Go!</a>
  </form>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("#id_country").change(function () {
      var url = $("#ProfileUpdateForm").attr("data-cities-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
      var countryId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input

      $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
        url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/ajax/load-cities/)
        data: {
          'country': countryId       // add the country id to the GET parameters
        },
        success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
          $("#id_city").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
        }
      });

    });
  </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Ta da! If you select a country, you will see just cities that filtered for country.
Is it magic, right? I learned all of these from https://www.simpleisbetterthancomplex.com, you can search with this title: 'How to Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django?'. Good luck bro!

Comment: thanks for the reply, I will try your code as soon as possible, let you know if it works. only one question for now, the "load_cities" function must be created in views.py, right?

Comment: so I got following error "self.fields['city'].queryset = self.instance.country.city_set.order_by('name')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'city_set'"

Answer (score 0):

Yep `def load_cities` function must be created in views.py, just above your main function.

Your forms.py should look like below and you can delete country and city definitions because you already defined your fields in class Meta:

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['website','country', 'city', 'year', 'image']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['city'].queryset = City.objects.none()

        if 'country' in self.data:
            try:
                country_id = int(self.data.get('country'))
                self.fields['city'].queryset = City.objects.filter(country_id=country_id).order_by('name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['city'].queryset = self.instance.country.city_set.order_by('name')
```

Could you show your main function that is renderer your form (in views.py)?

Comment: I added this function you wanted to, as edition of main post